# Mongoose static method error while calling it from mongoose post hook method

Tags: express, mongoose

I'm trying to call an mongoose static method from a mongoose 'deleteOne' post hook method. But while doing so I'm getting below error:
this.constructor.calculateAverageRating is not a function

```
reviewSchema.statics.calculateAverageRating = async function (productId) {
  console.log(productId);
};

reviewSchema.post("deleteOne", async function () {
  await this.constructor.calculateAverageRating(this.product);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Query middleware**

> **Note**: Unlike `schema.pre('remove')`, Mongoose registers `updateOne` and `deleteOne` middleware on `Query#updateOne()` and `Query#deleteOne()` by default. This means that both `doc.updateOne()` and `Model.updateOne()` trigger updateOne hooks, but `this` refers to a query, not a document. To register `updateOne` or `deleteOne` middleware as document middleware, use `schema.pre('updateOne', { document: true, query: false })`.

`calculateAverageRating` is a static method on the Model class, **not** on the instance of the Query class. You can get the model class by `mongoose.model('ModelName')` method.

```
import mongoose, { Query } from 'mongoose';
import { config } from '../../config';

mongoose.set('debug', true);
console.log(mongoose.version);

const reviewSchema = new mongoose.Schema({});
reviewSchema.statics.calculateAverageRating = async function (productId) {
    console.log('productId: ', productId);
};
reviewSchema.post('deleteOne', async function () {
    const Model = mongoose.model('Review');
    // @ts-ignore
    await Model.calculateAverageRating('1');
    console.log('this: ', this instanceof Query, this.constructor === Query);
});
const Review = mongoose.model('Review', reviewSchema);

(async function main() {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(config.MONGODB_URI);
        // seed
        const [r1] = await Review.create([{}, {}]);
        // test
        await Review.deleteOne({ _id: r1?._id });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    } finally {
        await mongoose.connection.close();
    }
})();
```

Logs:

```
7.3.4
Mongoose: reviews.insertOne({ _id: ObjectId("64b7608b39d77645ced9b411"), __v: 0 }, {})
Mongoose: reviews.insertOne({ _id: ObjectId("64b7608b39d77645ced9b412"), __v: 0 }, {})
Mongoose: reviews.deleteOne({ _id: ObjectId("64b7608b39d77645ced9b411") }, {})
productId:  1
this:  true true
```

**Document middleware**

> To register `updateOne` or `deleteOne` middleware as document middleware, use `schema.pre('updateOne', { document: true, query: false })`.

> In document middleware functions, `this` refers to the document. To access the model, use `this.constructor`.

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { config } from '../../config';

mongoose.set('debug', true);
console.log(mongoose.version);

const reviewSchema = new mongoose.Schema({});
reviewSchema.statics.calculateAverageRating = async function (productId) {
    console.log('productId: ', productId);
};
reviewSchema.post('deleteOne', { document: true, query: false }, async function () {
    // @ts-ignore
    await this.constructor.calculateAverageRating('1');
    console.log('this: ', this instanceof mongoose.Document, this.constructor === mongoose.model('Review'));
});
const Review = mongoose.model('Review', reviewSchema);

(async function main() {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(config.MONGODB_URI);
        // seed
        const [r1] = await Review.create([{}, {}]);
        // test
        await r1?.deleteOne();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    } finally {
        await mongoose.connection.close();
    }
})();
```

Logs:

```
7.3.4
Mongoose: reviews.insertOne({ _id: ObjectId("64b7621b4318463c330204f9"), __v: 0 }, {})
Mongoose: reviews.insertOne({ _id: ObjectId("64b7621b4318463c330204fa"), __v: 0 }, {})
Mongoose: reviews.deleteOne({ _id: ObjectId("64b7621b4318463c330204f9") }, { session: null })
productId:  1
this:  true true
```